# Spring JPA Derived query method groupBy

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Hi I was building an app and was wondering on how I can convert this query into a derived query method without using the annotation @Query:

```
SELECT address, COUNT(*) address FROM `employee` GROUP BY address ORDER BY address DESC LIMIT 5
```

I have tried it here is how I did it

```
List<Employee> countByAddressGroupByAddressByOrderByAddressDescLimit5();
```

This throws the following error

```
Invalid derived query! No property groupByAddressBy found for type String! Traversed path: Employee.address.
```

I was wondering if what am I doing wrong here thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.
Derived queries don't support `GROUP BY`.

Derived queries are intended only for simple queries, where the mapping between a normal method name that you might choose independently from Spring Data and the query needed for implementation is obvious.

For more complex cases like the one you describe other mechanisms are available, like annotated or named queries. Nobody wants to use a method name like `countByAddressGroupByAddressByOrderByAddressDescLimit5` anyway.

Comment: So I really need to use the annotation @Query in order to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think query derivation supports [group by](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords).

Comment: Correct, but you should either add more information or delete this and paste as a comment under the OP.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, derived queries do not support this. There might be other reasons besides simply not being a 'practical' solution.

AFAIK derived query methods are restricted to retrieving instances just for the entity type managed by the repository (you can retrieve `MyEntity`, `Optional<MyEntity>`, `Collection<MyEntity>`, etcetera) or projections that match the fields/columns used for the managed entity.

When you use 'Group By', you break with this resultset structure, you usually have to explicitly indicate which columns you want to retrieve or which operations you want to perform on the grouped columns (which would be impossible using just a method name).

**TL;DR**

You can't easily indicate the columns you want to include in a 'Grouped By' query result, so no, I don't think there is a way to use this technique with 'Group By'.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JPA's derived query methods do not support GROUP BY operations directly. Derived query methods rely on method names to derive the query, and they don't have support for complex SQL operations such as GROUP BY.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).